# Dúvida de como chamar varias imagens diferentes

Tags: c#, winforms

Sou iniciante em C#, estou usando o visual studio 2010 e estou com um projeto pra fazer e surgiu uma ideia, só que não sei como botar isso em código. Eu gostaria de botar 2 combo box ( ITEM e COR ), e uma imagem ao lado que vá mudando de acordo com o que o usuário escolher, por exemplo, caso o usuario escolha na primeira combo uma borracha, apareça a imagem de uma borracha, caso ele escolha na segunda combo box a cor azul, apareça uma borracha azul, eu já tenho a imagem de todos os itens e todas as cores, mas não sei como implementar isso no código. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: WPF ou Windows Forms?

Comment: Ou ASP.NET? Combo box pode ser qualquer controle de seleção de lista.

Comment: é windows form.

Comment: Você sabe como usar o ComboBox?

Comment: Cara, o combo box eu sei, os itens já estão lá. Eu queria saber se existe um comando que mude a imagem de acordo com o que for selecionado na combo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenho a seguinte ideia para o seu problema, mas ela vai depender que você utilize algumas convenções: as imagens deverão estar todas no mesmo formato e as imagens relacionadas à **Cor** deverão estar no formato *nomedoitem_cor.extensão*. Por exemplo, se estiver usando **PNG** como formato de imagem, o item borracha ficaria *borracha_azul.png*. Segue o código que montei de exemplo:

Crie uma classe `ComboBoxItem`. Ela vai servir para popular os combos com itens chave/valor:

```
public class ComboboxItem
{
    public string Texto { get; set; }
    public object Valor { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Texto;
    }
}
```

Popule seus combos usando objetos da classe criada:

```
ComboboxItem itemBorracha = new ComboboxItem();
itemBorracha.Texto = "Borracha";
// Utilize como valor o nome da imagem do item
itemBorracha.Valor = "borracha.png";

ComboboxItem itemBorrachaAzul = new ComboboxItem();
itemBorrachaAzul.Texto = "Azul";
// utilize como valor o nome da cor usada no nome da imagem
itemBorrachaAzul.Valor = "azul";

comboCor.Items.Add(itemBorrachaAzul);
comboItem.Items.Add(itemBorracha);
```

Use o evento `SelectedIndexChanged` dos combos para trocar a imagem (se estiver usando o *designer* basta dar um duplo clique no combo que o evento é criado automaticamente pelo Visual Studio):

```
private void comboItem_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // recupera o item selecionado do combo de itens
    ComboboxItem itemSelecionado = (ComboboxItem)comboItem.SelectedItem;
    // a propriedade Valor é a imagem do item
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"d:\img\" + itemSelecionado.Valor);
}

private void comboCor_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Recupera os valores dos combos
    ComboboxItem itemCor = (ComboboxItem)comboCor.SelectedItem;
    ComboboxItem item = (ComboboxItem)comboItem.SelectedItem;

    // substitui a extensão da imagem do item pelo nome da cor + extensão
    string imagem = item.Valor.ToString().Replace(".png", String.Format("_{0}.png", itemCor.Valor));
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"d:\img\" + imagem);
}
```

No código acima, estou assumindo que você esteja usando o controle `PictureBox`para mostrar a imagem. Substitua `"d:\img\"` no parâmetro do método `Image.FromFile` pelo caminho correto que estão suas imagens.

Comment: Cara, e se eu tiver que pegar as imagens da Resource como faço? Tentei aqui e deu erro.

Answer (score 1):

Comece por escrever duas classes para representarem aos itens e cada uma das imagens(cores):

```
//Representa um item ex: Borracha, bola etc.
public class Item
{
    public Item()
    {
        Imagens = new List<Imagem>();
    }
    //Nome do item
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    //Lista de imagens, uma imagem por cor
    public IList<Imagem> Imagens { get; set; }
}

//Representa uma imagem
public class Imagem
{
    //Cor da imagem
    public string Cor { get; set; }

    //Path para imagem
    public string Path { get; set; }
}
```

Na sua Form coloque dois ComboBox: cbItens e cbCores.

Cada objecto Item criado será adicionado ao *ComboBox* cbItens.
Consoante o Item seleccionado no `cbItens` a propriedade `Item.Imagens` é associada ao *ComboBox* cbCores.

Quando uma cor for seleccionada no `cbCores` é recolhido o *path* da respectiva imagem que depois é associada à *PictureBox*.

**Implementação:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cbItens.DisplayMember = "Nome";
        cbCores.DisplayMember = "Cor";
        CriarObjectos();
    }

    //Aqui são criados os objectos Item e Imagem
    private void CriarObjectos()
    {
        //Criar os objectos Imagem para o item borrachas
        //Cada imagem tem uma cor e um path

        Imagem borrachaVermelha = new Imagem();
        borrachaVermelha.Cor = "Vermelha";
        borrachaVermelha.Path = @"c:\imagens\BorrachaVermelha.jpg";

        Imagem borrachaAzul = new Imagem();
        borrachaAzul.Cor = "Azul";
        borrachaAzul.Path = @"c:\imagens\BorrachaAzul.jpg";

        Imagem borrachaAmarela = new Imagem();
        borrachaAmarela.Cor = "Amarela";
        borrachaAmarela.Path = @"c:\imagens\BorrachaAmarela.jpg";

        //Criar o item Borrachas
        Item borrachas = new Item();
        borrachas.Nome = "Borrachas";

        //Associar as imagens
        borrachas.Imagens.Add(borrachaVermelha);
        borrachas.Imagens.Add(borrachaAzul);
        borrachas.Imagens.Add(borrachaAmarela);

        //*********

        //Criar os objectos Imagem para o item bolas

        Imagem bolaVerde = new Imagem();
        bolaVerde.Cor = "Verde";
        bolaVerde.Path = @"c:\imagens\BolaVerde.jpg";

        Imagem bolaCastanha = new Imagem();
        bolaCastanha.Cor = "Castanha";
        bolaCastanha.Path = @"c:\imagens\BolaCastanha.jpg";

        Imagem bolaAmarela = new Imagem();
        bolaAmarela.Cor = "Amarela";
        bolaAmarela.Path = @"c:\imagens\BolaAmarela.jpg";

        //Criar o item bolas
        Item bolas = new Item();
        bolas.Nome = "Bolas";

        //Associar as imagens
        bolas.Imagens.Add(bolaVerde);
        bolas.Imagens.Add(bolaCastanha);
        bolas.Imagens.Add(bolaAmarela);

        //******

        //Adicionar cada Item ao cbItens
        cbItens.Items.Add(borrachas);
        cbItens.Items.Add(bolas);

        //Seleccionar o primeiro item
        cbItens.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    //Um item foi seleccionado
    private void cbItems_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Obtém o item seleccionado
        Item items = (Item) cbItens.SelectedItem;

        //Limpar o ComboBox das cores
        cbCores.Items.Clear();
        //Preenche-lo com as imagens/cores do item seleccionado
        cbCores.Items.AddRange(items.Imagens.ToArray());
        cbCores.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    //Uma cor foi seleccionada
    private void cbCores_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Obtém a imagem selecionada
        Imagem imagem = (Imagem) cbCores.SelectedItem;

        //Associar o path ao PictureBox
        pictureBox1.Image = imagem.Path;
    }
}
```